# Alternative to __callStatic for PHP < 5.3?

Tags: php

Is there an alternative in PHP 5.3's `__callStatic()` for PHP5.2 below?

The machine I'm using only has PHP5.2 and has no option to upgrade. Is there another way to simulate a callback for calling non-existing static methods without the use of `__callStatic()`?

I'm trying to simulate Laravel's Facade Design Pattern.

Comment: PHP 5.2 is not supported anymore: http://www.php.net/eol.php

Comment: tl;dr: No, that's why it was added to begin with.

Comment: In all seriousness, pay attention to what @feeela says: PHP 5.2 is not supported. It has not been supported now for nearly three years. More importantly, it has not had any security patches in that time, and there are a number of known security issues with it. I would consider a sys admin to be negligent if they still allow PHP 5.2 on their production server. It really is time to upgrade.

Comment: The client is the one that provides the hosting and I really don't have any control over it. I know 5.2 isn't supported anymore but I have to make do with what's given.

In the end, I'll just adjust the library I'll be working on. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
public static function callStatic($method) {
    $args = func_get_args();
    array_shift($args);
    return call_user_func(array(new self(), $method), $args);
}
```

To allow you to access the non-static __call.

Although to be fair, the comments are right - you shouldn't be using php 5.2.